# Xtext: Create a unique ID for objects

Tags: object, grammar, xtext, unique-id

I have a grammar that looks like

```
A: 
...
B:
...
```

I want to be able to give each element of type B some serial ID. So every time that the grammar creates a B object, it gets a (unique) new ID as a field.

I tried to do something like:

```
B:
myID=Tracer.getID()
...
```

where:

```
class Tracer {
static int ID=0;
static int getID() { return ID++;}
```

But I can't call external java class from the grammar.

It would be better if it's solvable without touching the src-gen files.

Thanks.

Comment: did you consider to switch for an exernal metamodel? the extension point `IXtext2EcorePostProcessor` is not supported that good anymore in 2.9+. (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=483209)

Comment: I'm trying to do it like in your blog https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/customizing-xtext-metamodel-inference-using-xtend2/ but I can't find org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator. Is it org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.Generator or org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.generator.Generator? Or maybe the interface org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IGenerator?

Comment: in xtext 2.9+ it is like described in the bug

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that in textual models, there is no such thing as object identity? I.e. you *fundamentally* can't say that any two objects in different ASTs are identical. You can only establish an interpretation of equivalence using diff algorithms.

That aside, if you only need a temporary identity, what about using Object.hashCode()?